# Skip "Sign in to your Microsoft account" (Windows 8.1 Setup)

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I have an RT tablet and updated it to Windows 8.1. The update basically performs the new PC setup.

I can't get past the "Sign into your Microsoft Account". Clicking "Next" does not allow me to proceed (and prompts me for an email address).

Clicking "Don't have an account" does nothing because its not linked.

The other two options are "Create an account" a "Privacy statement". I don't want to create an account, and I'm not interested in their perverted terms of service for an account.

In Windows 8.0, we were given the option to use local authentication.

It also appears Windows 8.1 is willing to re-use my Wifi connection information for the online account, but it refuses to reuse my existing local account.

How do I bypass this feature?

Comment: Thanks for closing guys. guys. I specifically asked about updating an existing installation nd using existing credentials; and not installing a new installation without credentials. How do 6 or 8 people make the same mistake?

Comment: hey @jww , ( Something that does have to do with the question )
but since i see your cryptopp answers alot and u said you wrote some of the Wiki can you answer about this ?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cryptopp-users/License/cryptopp-users/v5-B8BMjqmk/mc5dZs71QEAJ

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Click **Create Account**

On the next page, ignore all the textboxes to enter your names and details etc - at the bottom is a small link that says "**Continue using my existing account**."

[image]

This will allow you to keep using the existing local account

It's very sneaky of Microsoft to hide this option away. Most people who want to keep their local account will not be able to find this

Comment: Weird. My new Win 8.1 Pro setup shows a different 'Create a Microsoft Account' screen and doesn't have that option. Still haven't found a way to setup this new business laptop. Unbelievable that MS of all companies doesn't understand that we may just want to join the device to a domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go to you account settings and click on 'Disconnect'.
This switches your online account to a local account without any data lost!

Answer (score 0):

Click on create an account and then cancel or make a local account.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Create, then Cancel. No joy. It took me back to the "Sign into your Microsoft Account" screen without the option to use my *existing* local account (it apparently reused the existing Wifi settings).