# How can I stop Windows 8 linking a Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-8, email, passwords

Just purchased Windows 8. In a shared household (including people that do not have hotmail Microsoft Accounts) how can I set-up a generic password for the computer which everyone can use without giving out my Microsoft Account password?

I find that setting up a local password stops me from using features such as the Windows Store, yet using my Microsoft Account password means all users have access to my Microsoft Account.

Comment: Yes;  When you create the first account on the system there is an option to skip the process of linking your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Another possibility is to remove network connection at set up, and it will default to local username and password (instead of Microsoft account)

Comment: Related/possible dupes: [How to install/upgrade to Windows 8.1 RTM without a Microsoft account](http://superuser.com/questions/661416/how-to-install-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-rtm-without-a-microsoft-account), [Skip “Sign in to your Microsoft account” (Windows 8.1 Setup)](http://superuser.com/questions/661659/skip-sign-in-to-your-microsoft-account-windows-8-1-setup?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a second account if you would like to grant access without giving your password away.

- Open the Charms bar(by moving your mouse to the right side of the
  screen).
- Click on the Gear(Settings)
- Click on "Change PC Settings" at the bottom.
- Click
  on "Accounts"
- Click on "Other accounts"
- Click "Add an Account" under Manage other accounts
- At the bottom click on Sign in without Microsoft account(Not Recommended)
- Click on Local account
- Enter desired Username, Password and hint then click Next.
- Click on Finish

If the user needs to be able to install, change settings etc you'll also need to do the following:

- Under Manage other accounts click on the new user you created.
- Click Edit
- Change Account Type to Administrator.

Users will be able to log into that account instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

During installation, Windows 8 prompts you to use your Microsoft account as a Windows login, However, you don't have to use it, but create a local account, like in the earlier versions of Windows

1. When prompted to sigh in using your Microsoft account, select **Create a new account**

[image]

2. Then, instead of entering the info for a new MS email address, click **Sign in without a Microsoft account**

[image]

If you have already installed Windows 8 using a Microsoft account, follow the steps that Jeff gave.